# Error loading BMP file on C

Tags: c, vga

I want to open a bmp file that the user types on the screen. I have a function to ask for the image name and another one to load the bmp image:

```
    /**************************************************************************
     *  load image                                                             *
     *    Ask the user for an image file to load into screen.                  *
     **************************************************************************/

    void load_image(){
        char name[100];
        BITMAP image;
        save_frame_buffer();
        set_mode(TEXT_MODE);
        printf("Enter the name of image (BMP): \n");
        fgets(name,100,stdin);
        set_mode(VGA_256_COLOR_MODE);        
        set_pallete(background.pallete);
        load_bmp(name,&image);
        show_buffer(frame_buffer);
        draw_bitmap(&image,32,0);

    }


/**************************************************************************
 *  load_bmp                                                              *
 *    Loads a bitmap file into memory.                                    *
 **************************************************************************/
void load_bmp(char *file, BITMAP *b){

    FILE *fp;
    long index;
    word num_colors;
    int x;

    /*Trying to open the file*/
    if((fp = fopen(file,"rb")) == NULL){

        printf("Error opening the file %s.\n",file);
        exit(1);
    }

    /*Valid bitmap*/
    if(fgetc(fp) != 'B' || fgetc(fp) != 'M'){

        fclose(fp);
        printf("%s is not a bitmap file. \n", file);
        exit(1);

    }


    /* Read and skip header
    */
    fskip(fp,16);
    fread(&b->width, sizeof(word),1 , fp);
    fskip(fp,2);
    fread(&b->height, sizeof(word),1,fp);
    fskip(fp,22);
    fread(&num_colors,sizeof(word),1,fp);
    fskip(fp,6);

    /* color number VGA -256 */
    if(num_colors ==0) num_colors = 256;


    /*Allocating memory*/
    if((b->data = (byte *) malloc((word)(b->width*b->height))) == NULL)
    {
        fclose(fp);
        printf("Error allocating memory for file %s.\n",file);
        exit(1);

    }

    /*Reading pallete information*/
    for(index=0;index<num_colors;index++){


        b->pallete[(int)(index*3+2)] = fgetc(fp) >> 2;
        b->pallete[(int)(index*3+1)] = fgetc(fp) >> 2;
        b->pallete[(int)(index*3+0)] = fgetc(fp) >> 2;
        x = fgetc(fp);

    }

    /*Reading the bitmap*/
    for(index=(b->height-1)*b->width;index>=0;index-=b->width){
        for(x=0;x<b->width;x++){
            b->data[(word)(index+x)] = (byte) fgetc(fp);

        }


    }
    fclose(fp);

}
```

The `load_bmp()` function works fine because I´ve succesfully loaded other images. The problem I´m facing is with the input.

When I hardcode the file name like this:

```
    load_bmp("mainbar.bmp",&image);
```

The bmp file is loaded succesfully. However when putting the `name` variable I get `fp` to be `NULL` in the `load_bmp()` function.

Can anyone tell me what's causing the problem?

Comment: That´s what I needed. I did not read the man page, I´m sorry. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No problem. There's usually a hidden gem in the manual for cases like this. :) In this case, the newline is often overlooked, so you're not alone!

Answer (score 1):

The manual page for `fgets` says, in particular,

> Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is
>   stored  into the buffer.

If your `name` variable ends in a newline character (which it will if you pressed ENTER when entering the name), it won't match the file name. You need to get rid of the newline character at the end of the name.